# Pattern ReplaceAll warning

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Why does the following code give me a warning, but then still work?

```
a1={{1,2},{3,1}}
a2={"foo","bar"}
a1/.{x_Integer,y_Integer}->{x,a2[[y]]}
```

After a "Part: The expression y cannot be used as a part specification" warning, it correctly gives this:

{{1,bar},{3,foo}}

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed`. `a1/.{x_Integer,y_Integer} :> {x,a2[[y]]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rule:

```
a2={"foo", "bar"};
{x_Integer, y_Integer} -> {x, a2[[y]]}
```

> Part::pkspec1: The expression y cannot be used as a part specification.
>
> {x_Integer, y_Integer} -> {x, {"foo", "bar"}[[y]]}

Notice how `a2[[y]]` tried to evaluate, but issues a message because you can't use `y` as a part specification. Since Mathematica typically returns inputs back as outputs when things go wrong, when you later substitute values for x and y with your rule application you get:

```
{{1, {"foo", "bar"}[[2]]}, {3, {"foo", "bar"}[[1]]}}
```

which can now evaluate because the part specification is an integer.

As Shredderroy says, the proper way to do this is to use [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) (:>) instead of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) (->).